# Unexpected token import when using module installed with bower

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use a [Drag and Drop](https://github.com/asbjornenge/react-drag-and-drop) module made with react. I installed it using bower and included the `Draggable.js`, `Droppable.js` and the `index.js` files in my webpage like this

`<script type="text/javascipt" src="path to file.js"></script>`

However when I run my application I get 3 errors saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

and pointing to the 3 files previously imported

can anybody provide a proper solution to this problem